# Difference in the query execution on the db, between Hibernate session.flush() and grailsObject.save(flush:true)

Tags: grails

In my project I have lots of nested objects, and after few days server becomes really slow on every query execution.

I have removed flush:true from object.save(flush:true), which should avoid objects to be persisted with the database immediately, as I don't need object id, I think it is better to let hibernate decide when to flush and commit.

But even after this, I am getting some deadlock related issue with the db, I am getting the error:

```
    Timeout waiting for idle object. Stacktrace follows:

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC beg

in failed:

        at SecurityFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure4.doCall(SecurityFilters.groovy:13)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:

        ... 4 more

Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)

        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)

        ... 4 more

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object

        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1167)

        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)

        ... 5 more
```

After some digging more into the issue, some suggest that after few executions I should flush hibernate session manually.

As I have removed object flush from save call, should I go for

```
session.flush()
session.clear()
```

to clear hibernate session, if yes then what is the difference between these two aspects.

Comment: We are using MSSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a connection leak, or that you need to adjust the maximum number of open connections. This is configurable in the `properties` block in `DataSource.groovy`.

But to answer your question about flushing, there's no difference. You cannot flush a single object - Hibernate flushes all cached changes. `save(flush:true)` is just a convenient way of calling `save()` and then `session.flush()`

Comment: Thanks Burt, I will check the database connection properties

Comment: One more thing, do you think the error above can be caused by some deadlock in the code? because that's why I was trying to free some resources.

Comment: That's a good theory - you have a large enough connection pool, but you're occasionally holding connections too long.